# How to cast with GSON

Tags: java, json, casting, gson

Is there the way to cast a string value within json to an int-, long- or double-member using GSON?

What I mean, I have a json string, something like this:

```
{'timestamp':'1243274283728', 'distanse':'122.1'}
```

And I want to map this json string to object of following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
   public long timestamp;
   public double distance;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
TestClass obj = new Gson().fromJson(
   "{'timestamp':'1243274283728', 'distance':'122.1'}", 
   TestClass.class);
```

Comment: Damn it ... then I have another problem somewhere else in my code. Thank you